# Xcode: Table View Cell not automatically adjusting its height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, user-interface

**I'm having a problem with my table view cells as they do not adjust automatically with its content.**

I have a label for a title and another label for a name. There is a text view below the two labels which is never displayed when the simulator runs.

This is
[what the Table View Cell is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5kFR.png), however, this is [what the Table View Cell displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wh6R.png).

I have pinned all elements inside the table view cell to the content view using constraints. *I read up that adjusting the table view cell height itself will not work, so, I have to adjust the height from the table view itself.*

It is set to automatic but it is not adjusting as [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5om1.png). I have also tried to set the estimated height to automatic but to no avail. The only solution was to set a custom height but it would look extremely weird if the text view contains only a few text as there would be a large white space. **I did not add any code at all to adjust the size.**

These are the following constraints:

- [Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhAaS.png)
- [Name Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2vHW.png)
- [Title Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL3Oh.png)
- [Text View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS3DT.png)

Comment: You need to show the details of the constraints that you have set on your cell.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi! I added the constraints details

Comment: Your text view will size itself to 0 since it doesn't have a height constraint. You can use `sizeThatFits` to determine the height of the textview that will fit its text and then modify a height constraint to have that value.

Answer (score 2):

First You need to add height constraint for textview and add its IBOUTlet then you need to override the updateconstraint of cell and do following in update constraints method.

```
override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()
        self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.textView.contentSize.height
    }
```

and also for name label add bottom constraint.

Answer (score 1):

By default the `UITextView` will not resize itself to fit its content. While you could use @Waqas Sultan approach, I would recommend to let the `textView` size itself. To achieve that, just use this:

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Or, in storyboards, find the `Scroll Enabled` attributed and uncheck it.

This would make `textView` to size itself.

However, from the constraints you show it is hard to tell if there are really enough constraints to determine the proper frames for all the content - there are constraints related to `Review label`, but who knows how you constrained that label.

Not seeing all the relevant constraints in the `tableView` cell, I cannot guarantee that this will be enough to make it work as you expect (you might have forgotten about just a single one constraint, and it might be messing up your whole layout).

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy i would like you to try this way.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == desiredIndexPath { // the index where you want automatic dimension
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    } else {
        return 100 // the height of every other cell.
    }

}
```

note: Make sure that you do not give height to the label. Otherwise the label wont expand according to content.